# Dagger ApplicationComponent must be set

Tags: android, dagger-2

I need to expose my `OkHttpClient`  from `ApplicationModule` so I added to `ApplicationComponent`. Something like this :

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    final OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    return client.build();
}



@Singleton
@Component( modules = {ApplicationModule.class} )
public interface ApplicationComponent {

     OkHttpClient okHttpClient();

}
```

so I added the `OkHttpClient okHttpClient();` in the `ApplicationComponent` as you can see right above.

Now in my `NetworkModule` I use it like :

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides @ActivityScope
    public ProjectService provideProjectService(OkHttpClient client) {
          return new ProjectService(client);
}


  @Component( dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}, modules =   {NetworkModule.class} )
 @ActivityScope
 public interface NetworkComponent {

      void inject(@NonNull MyActivity myActivity);

}
```

but now when I get a runtime error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: css.test.demo.ApplicationComponent must be set
  at css.test.demo.main.projects.network.DaggerNetworkComponent$Builder.build(DaggerNetworkComponent.java:102)
  at css.test.demo.main.projects.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:159)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
```

and here is how I build it in MyActivity :

```
NetworkComponent = DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
    .NetworkModule(new NetworkModule(this))
    .build();

NetworkComponent.inject(this);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like to emphasize that dagger contains no magic—its is just plain java. If you don't give it the information it needs, the compiler will complain.

If you have a look at your `DaggerNetworkComponent.Builder` you will notice that it has a method called `appComponent(AppComponent component)`. This is where dagger expects you to add the appcomponent that your `NetworkComponent` depends on.

```
NetworkComponent = DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
        .NetworkModule(new NetworkModule(this))
        .appComponent(((App)getApplication()).getAppComponent()) // add your appComponent
        .build();
```

And it should work.

Comment: what if i don't want the application module for some classes for example in one class to full dependency I included the applicationModule in network modules but other classes only needs network module to fulfill the dependencies. Please help.

Comment: @eCDroid If the network module depends on the application module and some other module depends on the network module, then this other module also depends on the application module, but you could always split / refactor your modules or create new ones.